# Nested IFs and R1C1 Formula not working in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have the following formula which works perfect if I enter in Excel but when open the Macro it gives me an error and it highlights **FRANCE**.

> Compile error Expected: end of statement

I am really confused I don't know what I am doing wrong. Could anyone please look at this.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""AT_COM"",""AUSTRIA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""BE_COM"",""BELUX"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CP_COM"",""CZECH"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CZ_COM"",""CZECH"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""DK_COM"",""DENMARK"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""FI_COM"",""FINLAND"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""FR_COM""," & _
""**FRANCE**"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""DE_COM"",""GERMANY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""GR_COM"",""GREECE"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""IL_COM"",""ISRAEL"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""IT_COM"",""ITALY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""ME_COM"",""MIDDLE EAST"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""NL_COM"",""NETHERLANDS"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""NO_COM"",""NORWAY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""PL_COM"",""POLAND"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""PT_COM"",""PORTUGAL"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""RU_RUSSIA"",""RUSSIA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""RU_ENT"",""RUSSIA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""SEE_CO"",""SEE"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""ES_COM"",""SPAIN"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""SA_COM"",""SOUTH AFRICA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""SE_COM"",""SWEDEN"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CH_COM"",""SWITZERLAND"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""TR_COM"",""TURKEY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""UK_COM"",""UK"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""UK_ENT"",""UK PS"",""UNKNOWN""))))))))))))))))))))))))))"`

Comment: What version of Excel? Prior to 2007 you can only use 7 nested formula.

Comment: @David: I'm guessing it's post 2007 as the OP says it works perfectly in Excel.

Comment: @Jenya I see you have many many nested IF statements there. Maybe you should consider an approach using a lookup table.

Comment: @Philip thanks, didn't see that first time around.  I do agree with Jeny and Don George. If there's this many nested statements, some sort of lookup/index/match will certainly be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing VBA, and not opposed to UDF's, then I'd propose a custom function like this, which you can call from the worksheet:

[image: Screenshot of UDF in Worksheet]

```
Function LookupCountryCode(countrycode As String) As String
Dim myVal As String
Dim cntryShort As String

cntryShort = Left(countrycode, 6)

    Select Case Trim(UCase(cntryShort))
        Case "AT_COM"
            myVal = "AUSTRIA"
        Case "BE_COM"
            myVal = "BELUX"
        Case "CP_COM", "CZ_COM"
            myVal = "CZECH"
        Case "DK_COM"
            myVal = "DENMARK"
        Case "FI_COM"
            myVal = "FINLAND"
        Case "FR_COM"
            myVal = "FRANCE"
        Case "DE_COM"
            myVal = "GERMANY"
        Case "GR_COM"
            myVal = "GREECE"
        Case "IL_COM"
            myVal = "ISRAEL"
        Case "IT_COM"
            myVal = "ITALY"
        Case "ME_COM"
            myVal = "MIDDLE EAST"
        Case "NL_COM"
            myVal = "NETHERLANDS"
        Case "NO_COM"
            myVal = "NORWAY"
        Case "PL_COM"
            myVal = "POLAND"
        Case "PT_COM"
            myVal = "PORTUGAL"
        Case "RU_COM", "RU_ENT"
            myVal = "RUSSIA"
        Case "SEE_CO"
            myVal = "SEE"
        Case "ES_COM"
            myVal = "SPAIN"
        Case "SA_COM"
            myVal = "SOUTH AFRICA"
        Case "SE_COM"
            myVal = "SWEDEN"
        Case "CH_COM"
            myVal = "SWITZERLAND"
        Case "TR_COM"
            myVal = "TURKEY"
        Case "UK_COM"
            myVal = "UK"
        Case "UK_ENT"
            myVal = "UK PS"
        Case Else
            myVal = "UNKNOWN"
    End Select

    LookupCountryCode = myVal

End Function
```

In VBA, you can call this like this. I'm a little rusty on my `R1C1` notation so that might need to be tweaked a little bit:

```
With ActiveCell
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=LookupCountryCode(" & _
        .Offset(-1, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & _
        ")"
End With
```

Comment: +1 UDF for the win on this one. I'd hate to open up that formula while looking at the cell!

Answer (score 2):

The only obvious thing I see is the underscore in front of "France".  Is this out of place?

Have you considered putting this table somewhere - maybe on a new sheet - and using VLOOKUP?

Comment: I have tried to put underscore in front of France but again it gives me error: Invalid character. That's why I have posted this. Also this is just one part of a bigger macro.

Comment: I broke each If statement out on a separate line and it is much more readable - you might want to edit your source to do the same.  Anyway, it looks to me like the France line is different from all the others - there is a string "&_ on the France line that no other lines have, and ** in the description before and after France.  Try taking these out and see if that helps.  Particularly, the extra " isn't close, which is probably the source of the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Can I start by saying wow I think that's the biggest I've seen!

You need 3 " in front of France 1 to start the string and 2 to create one in the formula.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""AT_COM"",""AUSTRIA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""BE_COM"",""BELUX"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CP_COM"",""CZECH"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CZ_COM"",""CZECH"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""DK_COM"",""DENMARK"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""FI_COM"",""FINLAND"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""FR_COM""," & _ """**FRANCE**"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""DE_COM"",""GERMANY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""GR_COM"",""GREECE"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""IL_COM"",""ISRAEL"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""IT_COM"",""ITALY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""ME_COM"",""MIDDLE EAST"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""NL_COM"",""NETHERLANDS"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""NO_COM"",""NORWAY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""PL_COM"",""POLAND"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""PT_COM"",""PORTUGAL"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""RU_RUSSIA"",""RUSSIA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""RU_ENT"",""RUSSIA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""SEE_CO"",""SEE"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""ES_COM"",""SPAIN"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""SA_COM"",""SOUTH AFRICA"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""SE_COM"",""SWEDEN"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CH_COM"",""SWITZERLAND"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""TR_COM"",""TURKEY"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""UK_COM"",""UK"",IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""UK_ENT"",""UK PS"",""UNKNOWN""))))))))))))))))))))))))))"`

As an aside I'd write it like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""AT_COM"",""AUSTRIA""," & _
"IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""BE_COM"",""BELUX""," & _
"IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CP_COM"",""CZECH""," & _
"IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""CZ_COM"",""CZECH""," & _
"IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""DK_COM"",""DENMARK""," & _
"IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""FI_COM"",""FINLAND""," & _
"IF(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)=""FR_COM"",""**FRANCE**""," & _
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I've posted another answer but I think this deserves it. This is a classic issue and I like to use the following `VLOOKUP` / array -`{}` solution. A cheap `CHOOSE` function for a call formula:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(R[-1]C[1],6)," & _    
    "{""AT_COM"",""AUSTRIA"";""BE_COM"",""BELUX"";""CP_COM"",""CZECH"";""CZ_COM"",""CZECH"";" & _
    """DK_COM"",""DENMARK"";""FI_COM"",""FINLAND"";""FR_COM""," & _ """**FRANCE**"";""DE_COM"",""GERMANY"";" & _
    """GR_COM"",""GREECE"";""IL_COM"",""ISRAEL"";""IT_COM"",""ITALY"";""ME_COM"",""MIDDLE EAST"";" & _
    """NL_COM"",""NETHERLANDS"";""NO_COM"",""NORWAY"";""PL_COM"",""POLAND"";""PT_COM"",""PORTUGAL"";" & _
    """RU_RUSSIA"",""RUSSIA"";""RU_ENT"",""RUSSIA"";""SEE_CO"",""SEE"";""ES_COM"",""SPAIN"";" & _
    """SA_COM"",""SOUTH AFRICA"";""SE_COM"",""SWEDEN"";""CH_COM"",""SWITZERLAND"";""TR_COM"",""TURKEY"";" & _
    """UK_COM"",""UK"";""UK_ENT"",""UK PS""},2,FALSE)," & _
    """UNKNOWN"")"
```